# Variable is not assigned C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a problem with a variable:

```
private ScriptCorredor objetivo = null;
public List<ScriptCorredor> corredores2;
```

I'm adding a series of ScriptCorridor to the list

*I edit and add the full Enter method*

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "enemigo")
    {
        corredores2.Add(collision.GetComponent<ScriptCorredor>());
        if (objetivo=null)
        {
            objetivo = corredores2.ElementAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

then i try asign the first objeto in the objetivo variable with:

```
objetivo = corredores2.ElementAt(0);
```

but cannot be assigned, when I read the objetivo variable, it is always empty.

any idea what I'm failing at?

Comment: `collision.GetComponent<ScriptCorredor>()` seems not to do what you want.

Comment: Does collision have that component?

Comment: yes, I debugged it previously and the object does exist, it is more the list is filling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check (and maybe provide to this question post) your OnCollisionEnter() code and check that the object you collide with has the ScriptCorredor component attached. Also I think you should not access the component in the collision object directly, but through the collision.gameObject.
For example:

```
if (collision.gameObject.name == "MyGameObjectName")
{
    //If the GameObject's name matches the one you suggest, output this 
    message in the console
    Debug.Log("Do something here");
}
```

So I would suggest to try:

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ScriptCorredor>()
```

You can check:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-gameObject.html

Ánimo Ivan ;). Hope that helps

Edit: Full method with my suggestion:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "enemigo")
    {
        corredores2.Add(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ScriptCorredor>());
        if (objetivo == null)
        {
            objetivo = corredores2[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: agregue el metodo completo

Comment: find full method in the edited answer. added .gameObject as per my suggestion and corrected the double equal to compare objetivo == null. Without the full project and the gameObject components idea, it is hard to know what can be exactly your problem, so I suggest that you better try with the tips provided than asking for the full method in the answer, or post the OnCollisionEnter code and the gameObject component view in your answer so that the community can help you better

Comment: thanks, I have tried what you mention and still does not fill the variable. The curious. is that I have replaced with Object and I see that now the variable is assigned, of course the type I want to be ScriptCorridor and not Object
    private Object objetivo = null;

Comment: your gameObject has the ScriptCorridor component attached? Have you initialized the list corredored2 with corredores2 = new List<ScriptCorredor>(); ?

Comment: also try with the corrected if condition adding the .gameObject in the if (collision.gameObject.tag == "enemigo"). Also please post the error or whatever you are obtaining when you are not getting your desired result

Comment: also you can try corredores2[0]; instead of corredores2.ElementAt(0); (corrected in the proposed code)

Comment: it work add collision.gameObject and corredores2[0] and ==. Tnx very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the list at the top change it to:

```
public List<ScriptCorredor> corredores2 = new List<ScriptCorredor>();
```

You might be having an issue of trying to set index 0 of the list that hasn't been initialized yet. When you create the list variable its an empty variable. Adding `new List<ScriptCorredor>();` to it, creates the list and puts it into that variable. Now it should work.

Comment: tnx, this initialization is in awake